# Setting the width of TextView

Tags: java, android

I am creating a TextView and setting LayoutParams for the same.
But when i display the TextView the size is 0.

Below is my code:

```
TextView t = new TextView(getBaseContext());
t.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundbox);
t.setText(new String("Hi").toCharArray(), 0, 2);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
lp.bottomMargin = 10;
lp.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
t.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

The roundbox.xml content is:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#4fa5d5"/>
</shape>
```

Can you please let me know what should i set as width and height in the LayoutParams constructor. I am setting some arbitrary value but i want the TextView size to be based on the amount of text in it.

Answer (score 1):

To set the width on amount of text you can set `LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT` in width parameter. 
It will set the height or width based on the content size. 
see the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#WRAP_CONTENT) where you can find constant value to set the height and width as per need.